# Finding the trace of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $K^T=K$, $K^3=K$, $K1=0$ and $K\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2 \\-3\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2 \\-3\end{matrix}\right]$,

how can I find the trace of $K$ and the determinant of $K$?

I think for determinant of $K$, since $K^3-K=(K^2-I)K=0$, then $K^2=I$ since $K$ is nonzero. Then this implies $|K|^2=1$ implies $|K|=\pm 1$, where the two lines | | denotes the determinant.

But I'm not sure if $tr(K^2)=tr(I)=3$?

Comment: what does mean $K1=0$  ?

Comment: I think $1$ is a vector of 1's, not the identity matrix.

Comment: The determinant must be zero if $K1=0$ in this case.

Comment: @JohnU I thought determinant of $|AB|=|A||B|$ only if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same order. But here the vector of 1's is not the same order as $K$ which is 3x3?

Comment: first of all is there unique representation of matrix $K$?is  it unique or there is infinity such matrix?

Comment: For matrices, $AB = 0$ does not imply $A = 0$ or $B = 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)$ annihilates the matrix $K$ which's diagonalizable since it's real *(not clear from the hypothesis)* symmetric or since the polynomial has simple roots, moreover $0$ and $1$ are  eigenvalues of $K$ since $K1=0$ and since
$$K\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2 \\-3\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2 \\-3\end{matrix}\right]$$
now surely as the determinant is the product of eigenvalues we have $\det K=0$ and for the trace: there's 3 possibilities:

- if $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $K$ then the trace is $0$
- if $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$ the  trace is $1$
- if $1$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$ the  trace is $2$

Comment: can we determine matrix itself?

Comment: At least the trace cannot be 2 I think because of the property $K^3=K$.

Comment: @JohnU $K^3 = K$ forces the third eigenvalue to be 0, 1, or -1. All of them are possible.

Comment: what about fact that matrix is symmetric?

Comment: Yes I am not sure what I was thinking - I used 2 as the third eigenvalue when working on the trace = 2 case.

Answer (score 2):

$K$ has a nontrivial kernel so it is not one-to-one. What does this tell you about its determinant? To determine the trace, you could use the property that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: $K$ has a nontrivial kernel means that $|K|=0$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: if determinant is equal to zero,that means that one of it's  eigenvalue is equal to zero,because determinant is simple product of eigenvalues

Answer (score 2):

There are three matrices that satisfy the given conditions.

$K^3=K$ shows that all eigenvalues are 0 or satisfy $\lambda^2 = 1$. Since $K$ is symmetric (and presumably real?) we have $\lambda \in \{-1,0,1\}$.

Since $K e = 0$, we see that $K$ is singular, hence $\det K = 0$. We are given that one eigenvalue is 1, so we only need to determine the other eigenvalue to finish.

Let $u_1 = {1 \over \sqrt{3}} (1,1,1)^T$, $u_2 = {1\over \sqrt{14}} (1, 2 , -3)^T$, and $u_3 = u_1 \times u_2 = {1 \over \sqrt{42}} (-5,4,1)^T$. It is easy to check that these are orthonormal, $Ku_1 = 0$, $Ku_2 = u_2$, and, since $K$ is symmetric, we have $K u _3 = \lambda u_3$ for some $\lambda \in \{-1,0,1\}$.

Hence we can write $K = u_2 u_2^T + \lambda u_3 u_3^T$. It is easy to check that for any $\lambda \in \{-1,0,1\}$ that $K$ is symmetric, $K^3 = u_2 u_2^T + \lambda^3 u_3 u_3^T = K$ and that the other two conditions hold as well. Hence we do not have enough information to completely determine $K$.

The possible values for the trace are $\operatorname{tr} K = 0 + 1 + \lambda$, that is $\{0, 1, 2\}$.